# Android orientation changing -> Database dropped

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm haveing some problems with orientation changes. When my app changes its orientation, database is cleared. Is it something I'm doing wrong or is just its default behaivour and I have to restore and save database with onSaveInstanceState()

Thanks

Comment: can you show the implementation of the `Activity`'s overridden life cycle methods?

Comment: You definitely have some mess in your life cycle methods. Provide the source code and I'm it will be easy to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your manifest.xml file and change Activity<> tag as below: then check

```
 <activity
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem! Can you explain me why database is erased when orientation is changed??

Comment: when orientation changed activity is restart so oncreate() is called again dats y.

Answer (score 0):

If you are recreating the database in `onCreate`, then you will see this behaviour unless you also implement `onSaveInstanceState` and either `onRestoreInstanceState` or use the `SavedInstanceState` arg to `onCreate` to restore what you previously saved (or both).

The whole point of Save/RestoreInstanceState is for those times where the system needs to kill and recreate your activity without the user knowing, so you need to preserve the illusion that you have been running all along. The two most likely instances where this will occur are

1. on an orientation change
2. if your activity is in the background and the system is running low on memory.

Comment: SO, where do I have to create database? on Application?